# Bidirectional Search on undirected, weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, graph-algorithm

I am new to graph theory, and my question is whether I can implement `Bidirectional Search` on an undirected, **UN-UNIFORM** weighted graph (I want to find the minimum cost path between two vertices). The weight between vertices is almost always different (number between 1-100) and I read that the Bidirectional Search is only optimal with **UNIFORM** cost paths (or weights), which for me is not the case.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: any particular reason you can't use other shortest path algorithms?

Comment: @ChristianSloper Well, the professor said that the quickest uninformed  search algorithm will get a bonus (algorithm for shortest path from known A, B). I think my best shot is implementing a Djiktra Bidirectional Search , one from A forward, and one from B backwards. But I am starting to believe this is way too complicated and not at all documented so I can dodge mistakes (like the termination if a path is found, and when to terminate).

Comment: @Miketh You just need to run the [Bidirectional Dijkstra Algorithm](https://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahmto/math/2020/05/30/bidirectional-dijkstra.html) for this problem. Please consider reading the article, hope it will solve your problem. Let me know if you have any further query on this.